# Set default values for radio, checkboxes, selects, etc

Tags: channel, fields, fieldtype

When creating a Channel field, such as a radio field type, is there a way to specify that a certain option should be selected by default? Same question for checkboxes, select dropdowns, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not - although you could add some javascript to do so (using, for example, the [CP CSS & JS](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) add-on).

This would be a good feature request for Pixel and Tonic to add to their [P&T Field Pack](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack) fieldtypes.